# Create 'hostPath' volume on an existing Kubernetes cluster

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I am creating a spark cluster on Kubernetes and following the official documentation:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#using-kubernetes-volumes

As mentioned in the above link `hostPath` is one of the volume mount supported type for Spark cluster on Kubernetes.

I have created a cluster using `kubeadm init` command and using `spark-submit` tool to submit a spark job which creates driver and executors pods on demand.

I need to read some large files from this Spark application and `hostPath` seemed to be the only realistic option to mount this files on the cluster at this Proof of concept stage.

How can I create a `hostPath` volume on a Kubernetes cluster without an existing deployment yaml file? Since I am using `spark-submit` command, I don't have a yaml config file.

Trying to create a yaml file with kind `hostPath` is not a valid option.

Is there any other way using `kubectl` to create a `hostPath` volume or any other option with yaml config file?

Comment: A `hostPath` volume is almost definitely wrong – it will point at different storage depending on which node the pod is scheduled on.

Answer (score 1):

As @david-maze mentioned, `hostPath` is rarely a good option for pods since we shouldn't always schedule them into the same node.

However, if it's for test purposes on a local Kubernetes cluster. [Here is a doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/) describing how to create a hostPath PV and how to claim it using a PVC to mount into you spark pods.

Basically, here is the PV yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1

kind: PersistentVolume

metadata:

  name: task-pv-volume

  labels:

    type: local

spec:

  storageClassName: manual

  capacity:

    storage: 10Gi

  accessModes:

    - ReadWriteOnce

  hostPath:

    path: "/mnt/data"
```

Then

```
kubectl apply -f /path/to/pv-volume.yaml
```

Here is the PVC yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1

kind: PersistentVolumeClaim

metadata:

  name: task-pv-claim

spec:

  storageClassName: manual

  accessModes:

    - ReadWriteOnce

  resources:

    requests:

      storage: 10Gi
```

Then

```
kubectl apply -f /path/to/pv-claim.yaml
```

Then you use the pvc in the deployment resource you have or using a pod manifest

```yaml
apiVersion: v1

kind: Pod

metadata:

  name: spark-worker

spec:

  volumes:

    - name: task-pv-storage

      persistentVolumeClaim:

        claimName: task-pv-claim

  containers:

    - name: spark-worker

      image: spark-hadoop:3.2.0

      command: ["/spark-worker"]

      ports:

        - containerPort: 8081

      volumeMounts:

        - mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"

          name: task-pv-storage
```